# How to clip marks in Vega 3.0?

Tags: clipping, vega

Can someone point me to how to clip *marks* in Vega 3.0?

For example, I start with the spec from https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/line-chart/.  I then set the y scale's `domainMin:20` and `domainMax:50` but see its lines leak past y=20 and y=50.

I then thought [`autosize:"none"`](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/porting-guide/#layout) might correct this, but the clipping not only is applied to the marks, but to the axis ticks and labels as well.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the answer - set [`clip:true`](https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Group-Marks) to *marks*.